# How Do I change the Android´s default font configuration?

Tags: android, configuration, android-2.2-froyo

How do i change the android´s system font configuration?
O know that it´s a kind of low level configuration, but i´m not sure where it is located.
The idea is to make an option to set the default size, for those with vision disabilities.
I need something changeable, not hard coded.

Additional Information:
-I will generate a build of the System, so would be no problem changing any system file, class, or anything necessary. 
-SDK 2.2 - Froyo - API Level 8

Answer (score 1):

While this is indeed a low-level config change, it isn't really that simple. First, you need to have a rooted device with BusyBox installed. XDA developers made an app (search `Type Fresh` in the market) that changes the default font for you. I don't believe there's an easy way to do it manually, and AFAIK it's impossible without root and busybox.

Comment: Hy! Thanks for the good answer, but i concluded that indeed my question wasnt that good :-/  < first post here >
I made an update to make it more clear.

cheers